# restarting Phone and touch not working

Tags: hardware

The phone is behaving as if the power button is pressed forever (confirmed this by removing the power button - volume button strip), also the touch stopped working before this issue happened..(the os is booting after i remove the power button strip) is there any co-relation between both the issues ?? I gave the phone to a repair guy after it was water damaged.

my phone is redmi 6 pro (sakura)

thanks

Comment: Water can cause corrosion that continues to "attack" all the components unless it has been full cleaned. Most likely what you encounter are the late effects of the water damage.